# Multiplexing RF Sources to a Single Output

Tags: rf, antenna, multiplexer

I have two wide-band VCOs, one [800-1600 MHz](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/94/CVCO55BE-0800-1600-31920.pdf) and the other [1600-2700 MHz](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/94/CVCO55CW-1600-2700-23183.pdf) which I would like to multiplex so that they can share the same output (SMA jack). (They are both configured to produce ~5 dBm signals) That is, to achieve the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmWlwH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I tried using two "[RF Switches](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/249/MASWSS0115-18647.pdf)" in the following fashion, to achieve this effect, but the setup doesn't seem to work. The result is that both sources are significantly attenuated (about 10 dBm), no matter which source is selected. (Removing one VCO and switch, however, allows me to connect and disconnect the other VCO from the output as expected)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvTrRX.png)</sup>

What component/circuit/method should I use instead? I would eventually like this to scale to 4 or 5 sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first thing you have to identify is how powerfull is your 2 signals...
 is good to observ the absolute maximum ratings for an input power

[image]

as you can see the maximum rating for 2.5 volts is 27 dBm and 24 dBm for 5 Volts..

[image]

and here is the other table with 3 probably issues causes.

Comment: To be clear, do you think the switch configuration I am using is a good approach in general? The VCO output power (~5dBm) is well below the input maximum for the control voltage (3.3V). Is return loss the attenuation of the signal from the perspective of the isolated output?

Comment: I thing thtat your method is good but probably u will need another IC or maybe an amplifier on each wide band output if you need a stronger output

Comment: I forgot the blocking caps. Where would you place them on the output side? Two, at each switch output, or One after the node where they join?

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you built creates a stub line between the antenna and the switch that is switched to the "open" position. Whether that is a problem depends on how close you can physically locate the two switches to each other. With an SC-70 package you may in fact be able to locate them "very close" to each other. However if you haven't minimized the stubs, this could explain why you don't see the power transfer you expect.

You can avoid this (and save one switch) by reversing the switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTPVCa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The isolation spec tells you how much "leak-through" you can expect from the disconnected input to the antenna.

Also, this does not properly terminate the output from the unused source. Which your original circuit also doesn't do, as you drew it. If you need to do that you can look for a "transfer switch" instead of a simple double-throw.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work, even though I have never used switches from MaCOM. Having done a lot of work on RF switches, make sure you do the following:
1) don't forget the DC blocking caps
2) RF switches can be either reflective or absorptive (Gamma = 1 or 0 when off). Make sure your VCOs can drive an open if you want to use a reflective switch 
3) if you are using a thick PCB material, your 50 Ohm line may be as wide as 5 mm. Tapering to a tiny pad can easily kill 3 or so dB of signal. 
The switches we use all the time and they seem to work really well are from Hittite:
http://hittite.com/products/index.html/category/305

Answer (score 0):

I would use a two way wilkinson divider acting as combiner and a non reflecting/terminating rf switch. in your arrangement you cut the effective impedance from 50 ohms to 25ohms, it aint matching well thats why you are losing power as vswr(reflections).